# Conditional Left Joining in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two datasets.

Dataset 1 looks like the following:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Per  Gu  Ta
1123    112301  14  13
                   1124 112401  14  19
                   1125 112501 29  25
                   1126 112601  22  20
                   ")

dat1

    ID    Per Gu Ta
1 1123 112301 14 13
2 1124 112401 14 19
3 1125 112501 29 25
4 1126 112601 22 20
```

Dataset 2 looks like the following:

```
dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  Veh  Pert  Ti  ID1
1123    1 1 100 11231
                   1123 2 1 110 11232
                   1124 1 1 107 11241
                   1124 2 1 111 11242
                   1124 3 2 109 11243
                   1125 2 2 118 11251
                   1125 3 3 113 11252
                   1125 4 1 108 11253
                   1126 3 4 119 11265
                   1126 3 1 112 11268
                   ")
dat2
     ID Veh Pert  Ti   ID1
1  1123   1    1 100 11231
2  1123   2    1 110 11232
3  1124   1    1 107 11241
4  1124   2    1 111 11242
5  1124   3    2 109 11243
6  1125   2    2 118 11251
7  1125   3    2 113 11252
8  1125   4    1 108 11253
9  1126   3    4 119 11265
10 1126   3    1 112 11268
```

`dat1` is needed to be left joined with `dat2` by `ID` with rows having the minimum of at first `Veh` and then `Pert` of `dat2`. The final data will be like the following:

```
ID   Per    Gu Ta Veh  Pert  Ti  ID1
1123 112301 14 13 1     1    100 11231
1124 112401 14 19 1     1    107 11241
1125 112501 29 25 2     2    118 11251   ### in `row 8` of `dat2` the min value of `Per` is `1` but `Veh` is `4`;
1126 112601 22 20 3     1    112 11268
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a conditional join in R with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52648580/how-to-do-a-conditional-join-in-r-with-dplyr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat1 |>
  left_join(dat2 |>
              arrange(Veh, Pert) |>
              slice(1, .by = ID))

Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`
    ID    Per Gu Ta Veh Pert  Ti   ID1
1 1123 112301 14 13   1    1 100 11231
2 1124 112401 14 19   1    1 107 11241
3 1125 112501 29 25   2    2 118 11251
4 1126 112601 22 20   3    1 112 11268
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it this way:

1. `left_join` then `arrange` based on Veh and Pert
2. `group_by` ID and picking `first` values

```
library(dplyr)

dat1 <- read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text = "
ID  Per  Gu  Ta
1123    112301  14  13
                   1124 112401  14  19
                   1125 112501 29  25
                   1126 112601  22  20
                   "
)

dat2 <- read.table(
  header = TRUE,
  text = "
ID  Veh  Pert  Ti  ID1
1123    1 1 100 11231
                   1123 2 1 110 11232
                   1124 1 1 107 11241
                   1124 2 1 111 11242
                   1124 3 2 109 11243
                   1125 2 2 118 11251
                   1125 3 3 113 11252
                   1125 4 1 108 11253
                   1126 3 4 119 11265
                   1126 3 1 112 11268
                   "
)

# left join or order by Veh then Pert
left_joined_df <-
  dat1 %>% left_join(dat2, by = c("ID" = "ID")) %>% arrange(Veh, Pert)


# group by ID and picking first values
result_df <-
  left_joined_df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(
    .groups = 'keep',
    Per = first(Per),
    Gu = first(Gu),
    Ta = first(Ta),
    Veh = first(Veh),
    Pert = first(Pert),
    Ti = first(Ti),
    ID1 = first(ID1)
  ) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Easily done.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat_join <- left_join(dat1, dat2, by = "ID") %>%
  arrange(Veh) %>%
  arrange(Pert)

dat_join
```